# jconsole not connecting to java process on 1 server unlike another server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, jmx, jconsole

There are 2 servers running same java application.

Successful connection to server is running process with java version as below

```
java version "1.8.0_161"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_161-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.161-b12, mixed mode)

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xxxxx -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Unsuccessful connection to server is running process with java version as below

```
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=xxxxx -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
```

Network is open for ports which i confirmed with telnet.

jconsole on my desktop i used to test is of below version

```
JConsole version: 1.8.0_121-b13
Java VM version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.121-b13
```

Errors -

```
Secure Connection Failed. Retry insecurely ?
```

After retry another repetitive error as below

```
Connection Failed. Retry?
```

Comment: Please provide detailed information on what you mean by _"Unsuccessful connection"_.  Include all error messages and stack traces.  Show how you confirmed that the debug port is listening.  Did you run `sudo netstat -natp` on both servers and confirm that the port is LISTENING and owned by the expected JVM process?

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison. I did telnet to confirm that port is open. I am not sure how to enable debug for jconsole in windows.

Answer (score 0):

One highly probable reason is your *dns* is not properly configured in `/etc/hosts` file.

Java bug [6209663](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6209663) was also reported after which below article was updated to include its case.

Please see [this oracle's FAQ#5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/management/faq.html#linux1).

For quick reference I'd quote a part of this below:

> Run "`hostname -i`" command. If it reports 127.0.0.1, JConsole would not
> be able to connect to the JVM running on that Linux machine. To fix
> this issue, edit /etc/hosts so that the hostname resolves to the host
> address.

Comment: Thanks @ShanuGupta. However this is not the case since I was able to telnet.